# What is the best practice for injecting factories?

Tags: angularjs

```
angular
   .module('password_forgot', ['app.auth'])
   .controller('password_forgot', main);

main.$inject = ['auth'];

function main(auth) {
   auth.sendEmail().then(function(){
     //blablabla
   });
}
```

Should I inject `MyFactories` 3 times? What is the best practice for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing three very different things:

- a module: that's where various components (controllers, services, directives, filters) are registered. Modules can depend on other modules. In your example, you're defining a module named 'password_forgot' which depends on a module named 'MyFactories'. Your application is a module that depends on other modules, that depend on other modules, etc. The application is thus the union of all the components registered in all those modules. Note that factories are not angular components. A module named 'MyFactories' should probably rather be named 'MyServices'.
- a service: that's an angular component that can be injected in other angular components. In your example, you're injecting a service named 'MyFactories' into the controller 'main'. It's very unusual, and probably an error, to name a service the same way as you name a module. You shouldn't do that. The name 'MyFactories' is a pretty bad name for a service. A service should have a specific responsibility, like 'translate', or 'authentication' or 'products'
- a factory: a factory is a function that is registered into a module under a given name ('authentication', for example), and whose responsibility is to create and return the unique instance of the service of that name ('authentication'). This function is called once by angular, and the returned object or function is the service that is injected in the other components.

The line

```
main.$inject = ['MyFactories', '$scope'];
```

is only necessary if you minify your JS code. If you plan to do that, then I advise you to avoid inserting such a line of code by yourself, and to rely on ng-annotate, before the minification, to modify your code in order for it to be minifiable.

Comment: ok i update my code, how about now, has right? yes i have plan to minify, how about if i'm inject app.auth on my root module? so i dont need to inject on password_forgot, thats bad way?

Comment: Modules are not injected. That's incorrect terminology. Modules have dependencies on other modules. That's the correct terminology. Your new code defines a module 'password_forgot' which depends on another module 'app.auth', which isn't defined in the posted code. Services are injected. In your code, the 'auth' service, which is part of an unknown module, is injected in the controller 'main', registered in the module 'password_forgot'. That's correct code, assuming the module 'app.auth' and the service 'auth' are defined somewhere.

Comment: But as I said, you should use ng-annotate instead of explicitely defining main.$inject.

Comment: @JBNizet can you elaborate on why you advise against manually annotating ? I mean, we have tools that do everything for us nearly everywhere, you can't blame someone for understanding what he does

Comment: I don't blame anyone. I just feel that manually injecting makes code more verbose than necessary, less readable and maintainable, and a source of bugs. And I don't like bugs. I recommend what I find is a best practice.